# Dataset suggestion: video dataset with accurate depth and pose info

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, computer-graphics

Please suggest some datasets (can be synthetic, like rendered in blender or so) which have video frames (30fps preferred) with accurate ground truth depth maps and pose (rotation and translation for every frame).

PS: I couldn't figure out if this is the correct site to ask this question. Please let me know if it isn't and where I can ask this question.